# Markov property - application

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Ler $A$ be a set in $\mathbb{Z}^d$. I want to know if the following step can be in fact justified by using the Markov property, for the markov chain $s_n$, $A\subset A'$ and $\tau_{A'}=\min\{n\geq0:S_n\notin A'\}$

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\sum_{z\in A}{\sum_{k\geq0}{\mathbb{P}_x\left[S_j\notin A\text{ for all }j=k+1,\dots,\tau_{A'}\mid S_k=z,k<\tau_{A'}]\mathbb{P}_x[S_k=z,k<\tau_{A'}\right]}}\\
&=\sum_{z\in A}{\sum_{k\geq0}{\mathbb{P}_x\left[S_j\circ\theta_k\notin A\text{ for all }j=1,\dots,\tau_{A'}\mid S_k=z,k<\tau_{A'}\right]\mathbb{P}_x\left[S_k=z,k<\tau_{A'}\right]}}\\
&=\sum_{z\in A}{\sum_{k\geq0}{\mathbb{P}_z\left[S_j\notin A\text{ for all }j=1,\dots,\tau_{A'}\right]\mathbb{P}_x\left[S_k=z,k<\tau_{A'}\right]}}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

My problem is the last equality. To use the MP we have usually to conditional on $S_k$. Now by writing this I realize that maybe $\{S_k=z\}\subset\{k<\tau_{A'}\}$ therefore should be fine?

Comment: If $\{ S_k=z \} \subset \{ k \leq \tau_{A'} \}$ then *everything* here is actually just conditioning on $S_k=z$, not both, which seems like it would be a bit redundant. Still, if it holds then you could indeed use the Markov property here. Anyway, you haven't told us what $\theta$ is...